# Laravel validation for a numeric array of HTML Select input

Tags: php, html, validation, laravel

In Laravel, its easy to validate numeric inputs-

```
$rules = array('numericInput' => 'numeric');
```

**But not sure, how to validate a numeric array. What can be the rule for that. Or is it even possible by Laravel's Validator class?**

For e.g-

This HTML form submits multiple Select item to a laravel service

```
<form .....>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="objectIdArr[]" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

What Laravel gets-

```
( [input] => Array ( [objectIdArr] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 ))
```

what can be the rule!

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 3.x's validator doesn't handle arrays unfortunately as it expects each unique name to be a string.

You could however extend the validator class as a library (follow the docs for a decent example) and allow your extended class to recieve an array that then is broken out into strings and validated, if any of the strings fail validation the validator returns a failure with your custom message.